# How to compute distance for a matrix and a vector?

Tags: python, numpy, distance

In python, given one matrix of size `2*3` like
`A=[[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23]]` and a column vector `b=[mu1;mu2]`. If I want to compute the Euclidean distance between each column of `A` and vector `b`. For example, for the first column, the distance 'd1` is given by

```
A=[[x11,x12,x13],[x21,x22,x23]]
b=[[mu1],[mu2]]
d1=(x11-mu1)^2+(x21-mu2)^2
#second column
d2=(x12-mu1)^2+(x22-mu2)^2
# so on
```

So the distance can be scored in a matrix `[d1,d2,d3]` of size `3*1:`

I can compute the distance for a smaller matrix. But if matrix `A` is larger like size `2*100`, how to get all number of distances (i.e. a matrix of size `100*1` easily?

Comment: For [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), you can use `np.sqrt(np.sum((np.array([i, j, k])) ** 2, axis=1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use point-wise substraction, then square and sum the two columns:

```
>>> np.sum((A-b)**2, 1)
```

As noted by [@Gilad Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6400526/gilad-green), if `b` is shaped `(n, 1)` then a transpose will be required:

Either on `b`:

```
>>> np.sum((A-b.T)**2, 1)
```

Or on `A` (notice the summation on `axis=0`)

```
>>> np.sum((A.T-b)**2, 0)
```

---

```
>>> A = np.random.rand(3,2)
>>> b = np.random.rand(2)

>>> A - b
array([[0.21263611, 0.47988496],
       [0.91061396, 0.93371001],
       [0.66321026, 0.21926392]])

>>> (A - b)**2
array([[0.04521411, 0.23028957],
       [0.82921779, 0.87181438],
       [0.43984785, 0.04807667]])

>>> np.sum((A-b)**2, 1)
array([0.27550369, 1.70103217, 0.48792451])
```

Comment: `A` should be transposed

Comment: This would depend on how `b` is defined: `b = [[mu1], [mu2]]` would indeed require a transpose while `b=[mu1, mu2]` would not.

Comment: You can actually transpose `A` xor `b`. Depends on where you apply the summation!

Answer (score 1):

For [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), you can use any of the following methods:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.random.rand(3, 2)

In [3]: b = np.random.rand(2)

In [4]: Ab = A - b

In [5]: Ab.shape
Out[5]: (3, 2)

In [6]: A
Out[6]: 
array([[0.88888598, 0.71558933],
       [0.42653942, 0.80202214],
       [0.37195937, 0.24403248]])

In [7]: b
Out[7]: array([0.13348342, 0.91007169])

In [8]: Ab
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0.75540256, -0.19448237],
       [ 0.293056  , -0.10804955],
       [ 0.23847595, -0.66603921]])

In [9]: np.sqrt(np.sum(Ab**2, axis=1))
Out[9]: array([0.78003617, 0.3123404 , 0.70744541])

In [10]: np.linalg.norm(Ab, axis=1)
Out[10]: array([0.78003617, 0.3123404 , 0.70744541])
```